# Does Object.keys copy property names by reference or create a new string?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

Do items of `['a', 'b', 'c']` array reference object `o` keys? Or are they brand new string instances?

```
let o = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30};
let keys = Object.keys(o); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: They are just string values, primitive type, not object.

Comment: @Y.C., yep but not for `react-redux`. It considers them mutable somehow and reloads components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they were references, changing one of them in the `keys` array would result in changing the object property name as well. As you can see here this is not the case.

```js
let o = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30};
let keys = Object.keys(o); // ['a', 'b', 'c']
keys[0]='d';
let keys2 = Object.keys(o);
console.log(keys2);
```

Comment: True. However, it is strange then. I found that `React Redux` considers objects keys mutable in this operation and reloads components. This is why I've raises the question.

Comment: @Green, there's no trace of "React" and "Redux" in your question. In that case, the properties you refer to are defined by setter and getter methods defined by [a property descriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

Answer (score 1):

As you can read about `Object.keys` method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates
>   properties in the prototype chain as well).

So you question, *Does Object.keys copy properties by reference or create a new property?*, doesn't related with what this method does. This method doesn't copy the properties. As it is mentioned above, returns an array that **contains the name of the own enumerable properties of an object**.